# Select a row based on conditions for next row

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a part of my MySQL Table:

```
| id   | opentrap | openrect | lampgroen | lamprood | closeout | openout | limitswitchclose | limitswitchopen | traploop | photocells | rectloop | DateTime            | milliseconds |
|   92 |        0 |        0 |         1 |        1 |        0 |       1 |                0 |               1 |        1 |          1 |        1 | 2018-11-09 13:56:41 |          654 |
|   93 |        0 |        0 |         1 |        1 |        0 |       1 |                0 |               1 |        1 |          1 |        1 | 2018-11-09 13:56:42 |          262 |
|   94 |        0 |        0 |         1 |        1 |        0 |       1 |                0 |               1 |        0 |          0 |        1 | 2018-11-09 13:56:42 |          561 |
|   95 |        0 |        0 |         1 |        1 |        0 |       0 |                0 |               1 |        0 |          0 |        0 | 2018-11-09 13:56:45 |           83 |
|   96 |        0 |        0 |         1 |        1 |        0 |       1 |                0 |               1 |        1 |          0 |        0 | 2018-11-09 13:56:46 |          189 |
|   97 |        0 |        0 |         1 |        1 |        0 |       1 |                0 |               1 |        1 |          1 |        0 | 2018-11-09 13:56:47 |          402 |
|   98 |        0 |        0 |         1 |        1 |        0 |       1 |                0 |               1 |        0 |          1 |        1 | 2018-11-09 13:56:48 |          611 |
|   99 |        0 |        0 |         1 |        1 |        0 |       1 |                0 |               1 |        0 |          0 |        1 | 2018-11-09 13:56:48 |          916 |
```

I want to select a row based on alot of conditions and based if the next row has
`traploop = 1` or `rectloop = 1`

The query I want to use looks like this (but I can't figure out how to write a condition for the next row):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE closeout = 0 
    AND openout = 0 
    AND lampgroen = 1 
    AND lamprood = 1 
    AND limitswitchopen = 1 
    AND NEXTROW: traploop = 1 
    OR rectloop = 1;
```

This should give me:

```
|   95 |        0 |        0 |         1 |        1 |        0 |       0 |                0 |               1 |        0 |          0 |        0 | 2018-11-09 13:56:45 |           83 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
SELECT t0.*
FROM
  table t0
  INNER JOIN
  table t1
  ON t0.id + 1 = t1.id
WHERE
  t0.closeout = 0 AND
  t0.openout = 0 AND
  t0.lampgroen = 1 AND
  t0.lamprood = 1 AND
  t0.limitswitchopen = 1 AND
  (t1.traploop = 1 OR t1.rectloop = 1);
```

Comment: Yes!
Thank you, this is the fastest answer: 0.002s

Comment: As stated in other answers you **MUST** absolutely guarantee that `id`s are contiguous (no gaps).

Comment: I forgot to mention in my original post that because its a pandas dataframe with an autoincrement id

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach, using correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE closeout = 0 AND openout = 0 AND lampgroen = 1 AND lamprood = 1 AND
    limitswitchopen = 1 AND
    ((SELECT t2.traploop FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.id > t1.id ORDER BY t2.id LIMIT 1) = 1 OR
    (SELECT t2.rectloop FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.id > t1.id ORDER BY t2.id LIMIT 1) = 1);
```

### Demo

This approach is robust to the possibility that the `id` values may not be continuous.  The only requirement for the "next" row is that it have the next highest `id` value from the current row.

Comment: it works, but is slower than other answers: 0.115 sec

Comment: @MartijnvanAmsterdam But they're not the same query.  My answer would work even if the `id` values were not continuous.  If you don't require that, then the answer you accepted is probably better than what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the "next" row using `join` -- assuming that "next" is based on `id` and that has no gaps:

```
select . . . 
from t join
     tnext
     on tnext.id = t.id + 1
where . . .;
```

You can then apply the conditions to either `t` or `tnext`.

In MySQL 8+, `lead()` would be a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

A simple query that uses correlated sub queries but works if ids have gaps is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t AS curr
WHERE closeout = 0 AND openout = 0 AND lampgroen = 1 AND lamprood = 1 AND limitswitchopen = 1
AND 1 = (
    SELECT CASE WHEN traploop = 1 OR rectloop = 1 THEN 1 END
    FROM t AS next
    WHERE id > curr.id
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 1
)
```

#### [Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=77466e10d7a4ba481fea9b11f1229fb8)

Comment: Add indexes. Correlated query is the only solution I am aware of. I have changed it to one correlated sub query (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=77466e10d7a4ba481fea9b11f1229fb8) but it will still be slow.

Comment: "Add indexes" co-related subqueries tends to optimize bad on MySQL or MariaDB for that matter even with indexes... see demo with the "expensive" indexing needed.. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=c88dd8b29e0c13f127b2a0b3d5b56266 and the query still runs the same time without the indexes.

Comment: @RaymondNijland do you have better performing solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [Correlated Subquery with Exists()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table AS t1
WHERE t1.closeout = 0 AND 
      t1.openout = 0 AND 
      t1.lampgroen = 1 AND 
      t1.lamprood = 1 AND 
      t1.limitswitchopen = 1 AND 
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM table AS t2 
              WHERE t2.id = t1.id + 1 AND 
                    (t2.traploop = 1 OR t2.rectloop = 1)
             )
```

PS: This assumes that there are no gaps in `id` column

Comment: This one works, just a little bit slower than @pid answer: 0.003 sec